# Asp.Net Zero (Asp.Net Boilerplate framework) Session user is null when application deployed to IIS with load balancer

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

Asp.Net Zero (Asp.Net Boilerplate framework) Session user is null when application deployed to IIS with the load balancer.
After some hard refresh, it is coming with the right user.

[image]

Comment: Which version? and which template MVC or Angular? aspnetboilerplate uses client-side session, it sends the token(received in authenticate call) with every request. So if appsettings/configurations are the same on both nodes. Everything should be working fine

Comment: I am using 5.7.0 with the react client.

Comment: @Leo Did you manage to solve the problem. I'm facing the same issue after deploying app to elastic beanstalk. It works fine on my local.